# HM NIS Edit software get's freeze

Tags: nsis

I am distributing my software by wrapping the application exe in NSIS installation wizard. I use HM NIS edit software for editing the NSIS scripts. I recently got my editor frozen when I hovered on the default functions of NSIS like 'SetCompressor', 'BrandingText' etc. This is happening only in one system regardless of user. I tried to recreate the error but failed to do so.

The error occurred on the system with windows 7 professional OS, NSIS version 2.45, HM NIS edit version 2.0.3.

I re-installed the NSIS and HM NIS edit software but still the editor gets frozen when hovered. I searched on the internet about it but found no such error. I also compared the installed files against the installed files without error but found no difference. I used beyond compare tool to compare the file. So by this I concluded that there is no file corruption.

Please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug and should be reported on their [bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/hmne/bugs/). HM NIS Edit has not been updated in over 10 years so I'm not sure if I would hold my breath waiting for a fix.

You are also using a old NSIS version! At least update to the latest v2.x. This is probably not going to fix your issue though.

The two most likely reasons for freezing are:

- Bug while parsing the syntax file. Rather unlikely since it works on other systems but you could try to [update](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=265082&highlight=nis%20syntax) the [files](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Syntax_Files_for_HM_NIS_Edit).
- Bug while displaying the tooltip. Maybe the problematic system is using a special Visual Style/Theme? Non-standard visual settings relating to shadow or animation?

Comment: Did you try to figure out what is special about this system? Try creating a new user account and see if it is broken there as well...

Comment: Created the new user and yes, i am getting not responding for the application there as well.